# Get node name using xpath

Tags: xml, telegraf

I am using telegraf to parse my xml data. I am having a requirement to get the node name and the value. However i am not able to get the node name and i am able to get the child name. Below is Xml data and telegraf configuration:

Xml-data:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <report>
     <sampleduration>900</sampleduration>
     <network>
        <gateway>
          <red>103</red>
          <blue>105</blue>
          <black>120</black>
        </gateway>
      </network>
  </report>
```

Following is the telegraf-configuration:

```
[[inputs.file.xpath]]
 
 field_selection = "//gateway"
 field_name = "name(//gateway)"
 field_value = "string(//gateway)"
```

Actual output:

```
gateway = "103
        105
        120"
```

Expected output:

```
red = 103,blue = 105,black = 120
```

Also i tried below but its not working.
field_name = "//gateway/*/name()"
Following are the references - https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/parsers/xpath
https://github.com/antchfx/xpath

Comment: I may be off track here but should it not be //gateWAY/*/name() ?  (upper case used to indicate what looks like the "missing" bit)

Comment: yeah it was typo mistake